# Powershell SQL remove last row

Tags: sql, powershell

I have multiple text files with need to be imported in SQL Server management studio. I have written a code in powershell to import certain files. But I have a file which ends with a row contains only '---------------------------------------'

For example

**test|test2|test3**

A|B|C

Q|W|E

'-----------'

is there a way to ignore or skip this row. I already tried select-object -skiplast 1

```
Function AutoImportCommaFlatFiles($location, $file, $extension, $server, $database)
{
    $full = $location + $file + $extension
 ##   $columns = Get-Content $full | Select-Object -skip 1 | set-Content $full
    $all = Get-Content $full | select-Object -skip 3 
    $columns = $all[0] 
    $columns = $columns.Replace(" ","")
    $columns = $columns.Replace("||","Column Emtpy|Column Empty 2|")
     $columns = $columns.Replace("","Column Emtpy3")
     $columns = $columns.TrimEnd('|') 
     $columns = $columns.Replace("|","] VARCHAR(100), [")
    $table = "CREATE TABLE " + $file + "([" + $columns + "] VARCHAR(100))"
    $connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $buildTable = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $insertData = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + $server + ";Database=" + $database + ";integrated security=true"
    $buildTable.CommandText = $table
    $buildTable.Connection = $connection
    ## Added to function;
    $x = 0
    $insertData.CommandText = "EXECUTE stp_CommaBulkInsert @1,@2"
    $insertData.Parameters.Add("@1", $full)
    $insertData.Parameters.Add("@2", $file)
    $insertData.Connection = $connection
    $connection.Open()
    $buildTable.ExecuteNonQuery()
    $connection.Close()
    ## Added to function
    $x = 1
    if ($x = 1)
    {
        $connection.Open()
        $insertData.ExecuteNonQuery()
        $connection.Close()
    }
}
```

Comment: `$all = $all[0..($all.Count - 2)]`

Comment: I tried this but is still receive the error Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.

Comment: Well, you still need to write it back to a file, otherwise it won't make any difference

Answer (score 0):

and like this :

```
(Get-Content $full | Select-Object -skiplast 1) | set-Content $full
$all = Get-Content $full
```

Comment: That's only removing the first line

Answer (score 0):

Why you dont use import-csv command, Something like this :

```
$all=import-csv c:\temp\result.csv -Delimiter '|' -Header col1, col2, col3 | where col2 -ne $null
```

Comment: Because i don't always know how many colums the file has. I have more then 50 file to import. Everything works except the last row which only contains ----------------------------